# How to allow internet only to specific users while others need to access the local network?

Tags: windows, networking, lan, intranet, windows-server-2019

There are almost 50 users in my office. I want to provide internet access only up to some specific systems. Remaining systems need to be disconnected from the internet. 
But it must be interconnected by LAN and internal communication (through any intranet communication app).
Server 2019 is there, but it is now using as file server. No AD/DC is set up on the server. How can I make this possible? 
Please help.

Comment: You can do this with Active Directory.  You have a Server so implement Active Directory.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11b91980-972a-4ebe-a328-9a0d23c8010c/allow-and-restrict-internet-access-with-active-directory?forum=scogeneral

Comment: A firewall internal users must authenticate to would work as well. However, this question may be better suited to our business environment sister site, Server Fault.